# Custom the `on_delete` param function in Django model fields

Tags: python, django

I have a IPv4Manage model, in it I have a `vlanedipv4network` field:

```
class IPv4Manage(models.Model):
    ...
    vlanedipv4network = models.ForeignKey(
        to=VlanedIPv4Network, related_name="ipv4s", on_delete=models.xxx, null=True)
```

As we know, on the `on_delete` param, we general fill the `models.xxx`, such as `models.CASCADE`.

Is it possible to custom a function, to fill there? I want to do other logic things there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choices for `on_delete` can be found in `django/db/models/deletion.py`

For example, models.SET_NULL is implemented as:

```
def SET_NULL(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
    collector.add_field_update(field, None, sub_objs)
```

And models.CASCADE (which is slightly more complicated) is implemented as:

```
def CASCADE(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
    collector.collect(sub_objs, source=field.remote_field.model,
                      source_attr=field.name, nullable=field.null)
    if field.null and not connections[using].features.can_defer_constraint_checks:
        collector.add_field_update(field, None, sub_objs)
```

So, if you figure out what those arguments are then you should be able to define your own function to pass to the `on_delete` argument for model fields.  `collector` is most likely an instance of `Collector` (defined in the same file, not sure what it's for exactly), `field` is most likely the model field being deleted, `sub_objs` is likely instances that relate to the object by that field, and `using` denotes the database being used.

There are alternatives for custom logic for deletions too, incase overriding the on_delete may be a bit overkill for you.

The [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-delete) and [pre_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#pre-delete) allows you define some custom logic to run before or after an instance is deleted.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
def delete_ipv4manage(sender, instance, using):
    print('{instance} was deleted'.format(instance=str(instance)))

post_delete.connect(delete_ipv4manage, sender=IPv4Manage)
```

And lastly [you can override the `delete()` method of the Model/Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods), however be aware of caveats with bulk deletes using this method:

> Overridden model methods are not called on bulk operations
>
> Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a cascading delete. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.

Answer (score 5):

Another useful solution is to use the `models.SET()` where you can pass a function (deleted_guest in the example below)

> guest = models.ForeignKey('Guest', on_delete=models.SET(deleted_guest))

and the function deleted_guest is

```
DELETED_GUEST_EMAIL = 'deleted-guest@introtravel.com'
def deleted_guest():
    """ used for setting the guest field of a booking when guest is deleted """
    from intro.models import Guest
    from django.conf import settings
    deleted_guest, created = Guest.objects.get_or_create(
        first_name='Deleted',
        last_name='Guest',
        country=settings.COUNTRIES_FIRST[0],
        email=DELETED_GUEST_EMAIL, 
        gender='M')
    return deleted_guest
```

You can't send any parameters and you have to be careful with circular imports. In my case I am just setting a filler record, so the parent model has a predefined guest to represent one that has been deleted. With the new GDPR rules we gotta be able to delete guest information.

Answer (score 1):

CASCADE and PROTECT etc are in fact functions, so you should be able to inject your own logic there. However, it will take a certain amount of inspection of the code to figure out exactly how to get the effect you're looking for.

Depending what you want to do it might be relatively easy, for example the PROTECT function just raises an exception:

```
def PROTECT(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
    raise ProtectedError(
        "Cannot delete some instances of model '%s' because they are "
        "referenced through a protected foreign key: '%s.%s'" % (
            field.remote_field.model.__name__, sub_objs[0].__class__.__name__, field.name
        ),
        sub_objs
    )
```

However if you want something more complex you'd have to understand what the `collector` is doing, which is certainly discoverable.

See the [source for django.db.models.deletion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/deletion/) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from adding your own logic. However, you need to consider multiple factors including compatibility with the database that you are using.

For most use cases, the out of the box logic is good enough if your database design is correct. Please check out your available options here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete.