# How to get the user email after deletion in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was working with the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` and I want the email of the user to remain( after the user deleted). The user is a foreign key in my model.
Here is the code

```
class Text(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    text = models.TextField()
    user= models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET(??) )  # TODO : should change( remain email from the deleted user)
```

Comment: Refer this link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917926/custom-the-on-delete-param-function-in-django-model-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917926/custom-the-on-delete-param-function-in-django-model-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

That saves the deleted user's foreignkey.